# how to cin text

Tags: c++, text, cin

How can I get the user to input text instead of numbers in this program.
haw can i get the cin statement to accept text? Do i have to use char?

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int x = 5;
    int y = 8;
    int z;
    cout << "X=" << x << endl;
    cout << "Y=" << y << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to add these numbers?" << endl;
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    if (a == 1) {
        z = add(x, y);
    }
    if (a == 0) {
        cout << "Okay" << endl;
        return  0;
    }
    cout << x << "+" << y << "=" << z << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---EDIT---
Why won't this work?

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int x = 5;
    int y = 8;
    int z;
    cout << "X = " << x << " Y = " << y << endl;
    string text;
    cout << "Do you want to add these numbers together?" << endl;
    cin >> text;
    switch (text) {
        case yes:
            z = add(x, y);
            break;
        case no: cout << "Okay" << endl;
        default:cout << "Please enter yes or no in lower case letters" << endl;
            break;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you everybody!
If you're interested, you can check out the game I made here.
http://pastebin.com/pmCEJU8E
You are helping a young programmer accomplish his dreams.

Comment: Please remember to tag your questions with the relevant programming language(s).

Comment: You should probably get yourself a decent introductory book - there are a bunch in [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Look up the correct usage and rules that apply to the `switch` statement -- for example, here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are concerned with only 1 character response from the user, as in `Do you want to add these numbers?` might be concatenated by a `(Y/N)`, you should (in my opinion) use [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) function if you have intentions to read only 1 character. This is how I would do for an error prone 1 character input handling:

```
bool terminate = false;
char choice;
while(terminate == false){
    cout << "X=" << x << endl;
    cout << "Y=" << y << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to add these numbers?" << endl;

    fflush(stdin);
    choice = getchar();
    switch(choice){
    case 'Y':
    case 'y':
        //do stuff
        terminate = true;
        break;
    case 'N':
    case 'n':
        //do stuff
        terminate = true;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Wrong input!" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

**As a reply to your edit**

That doesn't work because you cannot pass `std::string` as an argument to the `switch`. As I told you, you should read just one character for that purpose. If you insist on using strings, do not use `switch`, rather go for `if else` blocks by using the string comparator `==`.

```
cin >> text;
if(text == "yes"){
    z = add(x, y);
}
else if(text == "no")
{
    cout << "Okay" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Please enter yes or no in lower case letters" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::string` for that purpose. Remeber that `cin` reads your text until white space. If you want to read whole line use `getline` function from the same library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::string`.

```
std::string str;
std::cin>>str; //read a string 

// to read a whole line
std::getline(stdin, str);
```